# Registering vue components globally

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue app that I created using the vue-cli

Im creating some components and I want to use them like this:

```
<template>
    <oi-list>
        <oi-list-header>Task ID</oi-list-header>
        <oi-list-header>Tasks Title</oi-list-header> 
        <oi-list-header>Task Status</oi-list-header> 
        <div v-for="task in tasks">
            <oi-list-item>{{ task.id }}</oi-list-item>
            <oi-list-item>{{ task.title }}</oi-list-item>
            <oi-list-item>{{ task.status }}</oi-list-item>
        </div>
    </oi-list>
</tempalte>
```

The probelm I have is where ever I use the list component I have to write the following:

```
<script>
    import List from '@/components/List'
    import ListHeader from '@/components/ListHeader'
    import ListItem from '@/components/ListItem'

    export default {
    name: "Tasks",
    components: {
        'oi-list': List,
        'oi-list-header': ListHeader,
        'oi-list-item': ListItem
    }
<script>
```

What I would like is for reusable components to either be registered globally so i dont have to import them and their sub components every time i want to use them, or some how have them load dynamically when I use them. Is this possible?

I have used [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) in the past and that doesn't require you to import each component in order to use it.

Please can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components

Comment: Thanks Ayush - ill give this a go

Comment: I do have the similar issue with Vue3, Vuetify3 and PINIA. Also using the setup keyword in <Script> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursivly go through your files and import them by their component name or file name.

```js
 const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)

 files.keys().map(key => {
     Vue.component(files(key).default.name ?? key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default);
 })
```

Comment: You shouldn't register components globally. Only import components that are used as a root component. All other components should be imported inside other components.

Answer (score 92):

This is easy to accomplish. You can register components globally in the main.js file.

```
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

Vue.component('my-component-name', MyComponent)
```

Now you can use `<my-component-name />` everywhere.

A cleaner way, without bloating your `main.js`, is to import your component in an index.js file in your components folder like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

Vue.component('my-component-name', MyComponent)
```

Later you can add this line to your `main.js` to load the registered components.

```
import '@/components'
```

the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: Thank you, this and Ayush's comment I think will answer my question, I will give it a go a report back. Thanks again

Comment: How can apply this method with a npm installed of component in the Vue CLI?

Comment: How can I make this approach work with autocompletion and TypeScript's type checking feature? Let's say I register a `BaseInput` component globally. In the `<script>` section of one of my other components I now want to use `myInput = this.$refs.my-input as BaseInput`. Now TypeScript complains that it doesn't know that class.

Comment: With createApp-syntax you can instead put those Vue.component calls inside a function that gets the App as param, export/import it and call it.
```const APP = createApp(App);
registerComponents(APP);
APP.mount("#app");```

Answer (score 22):

As another option in addition to @Odyssee's answer, if you want to avoid globals, is to create a file, say  `globalComponents.js`  with the following contents:

```
import List from '@/components/List.vue'
import ListHeader from '@/components/ListHeader.vue'
import ListItem from '@/components/ListItem.vue'
export default {
    'oi-list': List,
    'oi-list-header': ListHeader,
    'oi-list-item': ListItem
}
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
<script>
    import GlobalComponents from '@/globalComponents.js'

    export default {
    name: "Tasks",
    components: {
        ...GlobalComponents
    }
<script>
```

Comment: I like this approach, haven't thought about it like that.

Answer (score 10):

A **combination** of multiple solutions which i believe is the cleanest approach:

global-components.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const components = {
  'comp1':   () => import('components/comp1'),
  'comp2': () => import('components/comp2'),
}

Object.entries(components).forEach(([name, component]) => Vue.component(name, component))
```

main.js:

```
import 'global-components'
```

Answer (score 7):

Even simpler you may import global components like so:

In your `main.js`. (Note `Vue.component()` must be called before `new Vue()`)

```
Vue.component(
  'MyComponent', () => import('./components/MyComponent')
)
```

Comment: Will this mean they are all chunked? Dynamic imports are usually used for partial component loading in Vue. I dont know how webpack behaves if it is inside the global part.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Vue is throwing syntax error message.
@Odyssee 's answer seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking to do so using TypeScript, it can be done by chaining it with the `createApp()` method as

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import GlobalComponent from "./components/GlobalComponent.vue";

createApp(App)
    .component("global-component", GlobalComponent)
    .mount("#app");
```

Comment: Also works with just JS file, `main.js` file.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to repeat the component name, if it is the same name as the import. So this is enough:

```
import FirstComponent from '@/components/FirstComponent'
import SecondComponent from '@/components/SecondComponent'

const components = {
  FirstComponent,
  SecondComponent
}
Object.entries(components).forEach(([name, component]) => Vue.component(name, component))
```