# Unknown custom element: <VueTerminal> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to import an external component into my Nuxt project and it keeps saying the component is not registered. I've tried so many things from Google and i'm honestly a bit lost on the issue. Any help is much appreciated!

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hjemmeside",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "sass-loader": "^10",
    "vue-terminal-ui": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "hjemmeside",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en"
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ["@/assets/custom.scss"],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: ["~/plugins/Terminal.client.js"],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
    }
  ],
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: ["bootstrap-vue/nuxt"],
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
  },
  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: ["Terminal"]
  }
};
```

plugins/Terminal.client.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueTerminal from "vue-terminal-ui";

Vue.use(VueTerminal);
```

component/Hero.vue (Where i'm trying to use the component)

```
<template>

        <client-only>
          <VueTerminal
            intro="intro"
            console-sign="$"
            allow-arbitrary
            height="500px"
            @command="onCliCommand"
          ></VueTerminal>
        </client-only>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onCliCommand(data, resolve, reject) {
      // typed command is available in data.text
      // don't forget to resolve or reject the Promise
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('')
      }, 300)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="sass">
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registering vue components globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644198/registering-vue-components-globally)

Comment: You should use `Vue.component` or import it locally and add it to the `components` key of your own component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either make a component available globally or import it in the component where you want to use it:

If you want to make the component available globally you should use this in your plugin:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueTerminal from "vue-terminal-ui";

Vue.component('vue-terminal', VueTerminal)
```

You can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component).

If you want to import it locally using the options API, you import it in your component and declare it in the components option:

```js
<script>
import VueTerminal from 'vue-terminal-ui';
export default {
  components: {
    VueTerminal,
  },
};
</script>
```

If you want to import it locally using the composition API:

```js
<script setup>
import VueTerminal from 'vue-terminal-ui';
</script>
```

Also it is recommended to use kebab-case for components, when declaring them in the template. Since HTML isn't case sensitive. You can read about this in the [Vue Style Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/?redirect=true#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended)

Update: [The Vue 3 documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration) says kebab-case is no longer the recommended component casing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple fix
first import the component in this case VueTerminal
and then add another field or option to export
like this

```
export default {
  components: {
    VueTerminal
  },
  // other code
}
```